# String(x) puts "optional" in the output

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm writing a little program that reads and writes text files into an NSTableView. I had the reading working fine, and then moved onto the writing. And I got...

```
FR Optional(0) Optional(0) Optional(0) Optional(0) Optional(46.29) Optional(0)
```

I understand *why* this is happening: the values are NSNumbers in a dictionary, so they are, by definition, optional. But obviously this is not useful output.

Is there an *easy* way to output the value without the `Optional` and any similar bumpf?

Comment: what code are you using to output the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values you write are held in an (optional) array, then `.flatMap`, prior to printing, will do the trick for you

```
// myOptionalDoubles : [Double?]
myOptionalDoublesForWriting = myOptionalDoubles.flatMap { $0 }
```

Using `.flatMap` like this, you unwrap any non-nil values in the array `myOptionalDoubles`, and return an array `myOptionalDoublesForWriting` of type `[Double]` (non-optional). Any `nil` entries in `myOptionalDoubles` will not follow to `myOptionalDoublesForWriting`.

---

If you don't want to lose information about optional entries, you can use `.map` instead:

```
// myOptionalDoubles : [Double?]
var myOptionalDoublesForWriting = myOptionalDoubles.map { $0 ?? 0.0 }
```

In this case, you make use of the *[nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)* to *either* unwrap each (non-`nil`) array entry, or, if it's `nil`, give it value `0.0`. As above, the mapped to array `myOptionalDoublesForWriting` will be of non-optional type `[Double]`.

Comment: "Any nil entries in myOptionalDoubles will not follow to myOptionalDoublesForWriting." Ok, so I'm thinking an expansion of this might kill two birds with one stone... the other issue I have is that any nil entries "to the left" on the line have to have placeholder "0"s inserted. So this...

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: Misunderstood your comment at first. Added an example using the `.map()` option instead, inserting zeroes instead of removing those entries.

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks dfri!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz You're very welcome. Happy Christmas! :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you see Optional(n) is because you're printing the optional without unwrapping.

I suggest you re-read the optionals chapter in the Apple book to get a better grasp at *why* this is happening to you.

The short version is, an Optional is a type, in fact if you look at the Swift source code, you will find that's it's just an Enum!

```
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : _Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(Wrapped)
    /// Construct a `nil` instance.
    public init()
    /// Construct a non-`nil` instance that stores `some`.
    public init(_ some: Wrapped)
    /// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func map<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
    /// Returns `nil` if `self` is nil, `f(self!)` otherwise.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func flatMap<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?
    /// Create an instance initialized with `nil`.
    public init(nilLiteral: ())
}
```

So if your values are Optionals, you have to unwrap them to see their values.

Take a look at this code and try to guess the output:

```
var code: String? = "hello"

if let code = code where code == "hello" {
    print(code)
}

var upperCase = code?.uppercaseString
print(upperCase)
```

Output:

Did you figure it out?

It looks like this:

```
hello 
Optional("HELLO")
```

Why does the first hello print ok?

Because it's being unwrapped in the `if let` statement.

But the second one, `upperCase` is never unwrapped, so an Optional will remain optional (unless unwrapped). `code?.uppercaseString` returns a new Optional. By printing it directly, we get what you see.

If you want to extract the value the optional is holding you have two operators. `?` and `!`.

The first one is usually preferred, but if you're *sure*  that the value is ok, you can use force the unwrap by using `!`, so you could do

`print(uppercase!)`

Careful tho, because if upperCase happens to be nil, you'd get a **runtime crash**.

Comment: I agree with @Martin Marconcini... If you do add the "!" after a variable make sure that variable never goes nil. If it does, the app will crash!

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of *why* it's happening, as I mentioned in the question. I'm looking for the simplest solution to deal with the case where it may indeed be nil. Hundreds (literally) of if data["F3"] != nil  looks like ass and hides the logic under the code. The .flatMap suggested below has the disadvantage of hiding which ones are nil, which is still useful information. A perfect solution would be "return the unwrapped value or zero".

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but you asked: "Is there an easy way to output the value without the Optional and any similar bump". Yes, you print using the optional unwrapping. What you _really_ seem to want is to print the values regardless of their contents and if one happens to be nil, then replace it with zero. This is not stated in the original question. Regardless, I don't have a playground next to me right now, but the solution given by the other user may work (map). Tho I think his syntax is wrong It would be closer to `map{$0.1 ?? 0.0}` but I haven't tested it.